# You don't have permission to access /cacti/ on this server

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, cacti

I have installed cacti on a server and when trying to connect it via web "http://192.168.1.3/cacti/" then getting error like "You don't have permission to access /cacti/ on this server".

I search on google and try to change /etc/httpd/conf.d/cacti.conf file as per below-

default is-

```
# Cacti: An rrd based graphing tool
#
Alias /cacti    /usr/share/cacti

<Directory /usr/share/cacti/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

I tried to change as-

```
# Cacti: An rrd based graphing tool
#
Alias /cacti    /usr/share/cacti

    <Directory /usr/share/cacti/>
            Order Deny,Allow
            #Deny from all
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

After this change and restarting httpd service not getting any error on webpage instead getting blank page with 403 forbidden error in explorer tab.

Also try to allow specific ips, but no luck. Some other suggestions also checked but not able to get solution.

I will be very thankfull for any prompt help.

Comment: some one can help me in this or guide me if I should take this problem in any other platform like serverfault or database administrator etc.

Comment: Try:   
Deny from None  
Allow from all

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I found that the following format solved my instance of this issue:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    # httpd 2.4
    Require all granted
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    # httpd 2.2
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
</IfModule>
```

I've verified this on CentOS 7 and Rocky 9. It was only after an infuriatingly long period that I noticed the comment at the head of the file:

```
# For security reasons, the Cacti web interface is accessible only to
# localhost in the default configuration. If you want to allow other clients
# to access your Cacti installation, change the httpd ACLs below.
# For example:
# On httpd 2.4, change "Require host localhost" to "Require all granted".
# On httpd 2.2, change "Allow from localhost" to "Allow from all".
```

I hope this solution helps anyone else struggling with this issue.